# How can I understand the definition $(a-ε, a+ε)\thinspace\cap(D\thinspace\backslash{\{a\}})= \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let D be a subset of $\mathbb {R}$ and $a\in\mathbb {R}$.
The definition for a point of convergence of a set D:  
 $(a-ε, a+ε)\thinspace\cap(D\thinspace\backslash{\{a\}})= \emptyset$

I even drew it for better understanding: [image: picture1]

It is clearly shown that in the interval $(a-ε, a+ε)$ has an infinite number of elements of set D including point a. But when I look at the intersection of the interval $(a-ε, a+ε)$ and $(D\thinspace\backslash{\{a\}})$ I don't get an empty set but rather an infinite number of elements of a set D without a as the left side of the definition directs.

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be rather $D\cap ((a-\varepsilon ,a+\varepsilon )\setminus \{a\})$.

Comment: @Surb That’s the same thing, isn’t it?

Comment: If $a$ is in $D$ then it looks like this defines an isolated point. What are the properties of $D$ that you have?

Comment: Intuitively, if $\epsilon$ is used as usual in analysis, we have that the collection of intervals $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ is "shrinking" into $\{ a \}$ alone. But this is excluded from $D \setminus \{ a \}$, and thus the intersection must be empty.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so in other words: the definition above is actually for an isolated point? What does an isolated point have to do with a point of convergence of a set? I don't see a connection :(

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, checked on wiki. The definition of a isolated point states $(a-ε, a+ε)\thinspace\cap D= \emptyset$.

Comment: @ I'm currently working on limits (of functions). Before I even got to the limits, there is a section before with basic definitions of inner point, outer point and a point of convergence of a set. The latter definition is then included in the definition of a limit (the basic one, about the functions). It is little complicated, I know. Can't help, I have a weird professor for analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki's definition of [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) says:

> "if there exists a neighborhood of point $a$ which does not contain **any other** points of $D$."

This means: $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cap D \setminus \{ a \} = \emptyset$, for some $\epsilon$.

Regarding [limit (or accumulation) point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) the definition is:

> "every neighbourhood of $a$ (with respect to the topology) also contains a point of $D$ **other than** $a$ itself."

This means: $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cap D \setminus \{ a \} \ne \emptyset$, for every $\epsilon$.

In conclusion, the two definitions are **different**: the first one has $=$ and has "there is at least one neighborhood (existential quantifier)..." while the second has $\ne$ and has "for every neighborhood (universal quantifier)...".